# My son is discouraged

Tags: behavior, discipline, education, school

I have a 10-yr-old son.
He's a fifth grader right now and I have been really worried about his attitude toward homework and everything that has to do with studying.  He constantly calls himself stupid and has no motivation for getting good grades.
He has many friends, so I have no worries in that aspect. He is half American, half Japanese. He goes to a public Japanese school. At first, I thought maybe it was because of his inability to understand the Japanese language as well as other children his age since we were living in the States until he was 3 and a half.
But, in my opinion, him being 10, it's been long enough to make up for that time now.
I try to come up with things that might motivate him, but it doesn't seem to work.
People have told me that around the time when he's 12, he will be able to cover everything that's been taught in elementary school, but I'm not completely buying it.
How can I motivate him?

Comment: *"But, in my opinion, him being 10, it's been long enough to make up for that time now."* That's a very weird thing to say. Can he speak Japanese as well as the other kids, or can he not?

Comment: I said that because when we first moved to Japan, he couldn't understand what the teachers were saying in kindergarten for a little while. He has no problem conversing in Japanese at all now. He can speak and understand just like the rest of the kids. It's not like he has outstandingly less amount of vocabularies compared to his friends.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't give enough information. He can have conversations without any problem, but I have no idea how much he's being able to understand the teachers in his classes at school.

Comment: And also... about a year after we moved here, his dad and I got a divorce, which I am very ashamed of...  So I'm not home till around 7pm, and I need to do house chores like cooking, doing the laundry, cleaning... So except for weekends, I haven't been able to spend much quality time with him. I feel horrible about it. When I'm home before he gets home from school, which happens probably once every 2-3 months, he seems really happy.

Comment: Can you afford a babysitter/tutor? Sounds like he may just need a little extra adult attention now that dad is gone...

Comment: That could be an option, but he's exceptionally shy around adults he doesn't know... plus, it's not common to hire babysitters or tutors here... I sound like I'm just completely brushing you off despite your advice. I'm so sorry. But I think your guess about him lacking adult attention is so on point. I started to wonder if it's just that or if he has some disability that is hard to be recognized by others.

Comment: Does your son have any issues with other children bullying him, or perhaps suggesting that since he's only half Japanese he won't be as smart or as capable?  I could imagine many such issues at at that age.

Comment: He used to be teased about being half Japanese when he was in the first and second grade, but they were never so serious to the point where they kept him from going to school. But he could've been just acting okay and they might've been more serious than I was thinking.

Comment: It's not like I want him to get straight A's, but I want him to at least do okay with his schoolwork. Recently, all he does is hang out with his friends or play video games, and sometimes he doesn't start his homework till around 10pm. All discouraged and with sloppy handwriting.

Comment: There seems to be at least some tutoring available in Japan: http://www.tokyoacademics.com/

Comment: Thank you for the resource.  He is actually going to a cram school, but I can't afford this type of one-on-one tutoring. He's also on a soccer team. He's been telling me that he wants to quit both though. He just doesn't want to do anything...

Comment: Just throwing this out there: perhaps he's incredibly bored by school. Either the teaching style doesn't suite him (lots of sit & listen?) or the material is boring him (lots of repetition of topics he's already understood?). Does that seem like a possibility?

Comment: @deceze Yea it does seem like a possibility. He is probablt bored from just sitting and listening to the teacher speak. I don't think the reason why he's bored is because he's continuously listening to what he's already understood though. If that's the case, he wouldn't be doing so bad in any of he classes I would think. I've been thinking my son and his new teacher aren't such a great match. Probably the worst of the 4+ years with any other teachers he's had. What sucks is that in our country, the same teacher teaches every single class throughout a year. :/

Comment: @Miki Well, I've had this problem myself in school: the first few years were pretty boring to me, so I stopped paying attention at some point, which made me fall behind. Just saying it's one possible scenario. If that's the case here, I don't have a good solution unfortunately; the solution for me was to get through school by hook or by crook and then thrive in the working environment.

Comment: @deceze Thank you for your reply. Some of his teachers have told me that my son seems he's not very interested in studying, which I think is probably because he's bored as you pointed out. The only classes he seems to like are arts and crafts, music, some science, and some P.E., which are mostly unnecessary for any exams to come in the future for getting into a high school (which is mandatory here), college or univesity. I wanna ask you a question. Have you had any struggles in your adulthood which resulted from the past indifference to schoolwork? I'm sorry if I sounded rude.

Comment: @Miki I would say it has certainly put me on a different path in life. Had I done better in school I may have stayed in it longer and perhaps gone on to university. Since I didn't, I have worked in 4 different countries in a variety of jobs before settling on a programming career. Couldn't say if the alternative would have been better or not; I certainly struggled a bit at first, but I ended up in a place I'm pretty happy with. A good education will certainly open more doors from the get go, but it's not the only possible way...

Comment: By mandatory, I meant passing an exam is required here for kids to get into any kind of high school here.

Comment: @deceze Ah... Your comments somewhat put me at ease. Thank you so much, deceze. I would think people with way more options than others are few that go to Ivy League universities. I realized this after I grew up. Other than that, many are struggling the same way as others. This is only MY opinion though. Thanks a lot. I'll try not to dwell on this too much.

Comment: I will try to help my son with his homework as much as I can if it is a subject he has no interest whatsoever so that he will at least be able to graduate from a high school. I hope he will find his true interest by then... :)

Comment: If there's any way in which you can *make* the subjects interesting, that might help a lot. E.g. show their practical application to something in daily life, or simply show how it connects to a topic he *is* interested in. Perhaps he needs some time in "the real world" to figure out things he wants to know more about; that could be a part time job, interning, extended travelling or something else interesting to do "in real life" that will give him a basis for pursuing more theoretical study. Easy to say, hard to do, but I wish I'd have had that in my teenage years for sure.

Comment: @deceze You're such a good adviser! I can clearly see what I was lacking from your last comment. It sucks but I've been only putting him in harder situations by repetitively telling him "do your homework!" on a daily basis. How can he be interested in anything like that, huh...? If you don't mind, will you write a brief answer so that I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: @deceze will you let me ask you one last question? Do you think his indifferece also has something to do with my split with his dad? So sorry to keep bugging you...

Comment: Hard to say. I do think that kids typically want a role model, and usually that means an adult of their own gender. If his dad isn't around anymore, he probably has nobody he feels he wants to emulate, which depletes him of a "natural source of motivation", if you know what I mean.

Comment: A gentle reminder that comments are not for extended discussion; I recommend [chat] to continue :)

Comment: @Erica Will be careful from now on :)

Comment: FWIW "He constantly calls himself stupid" is destructive behavior [because of self-fulfilling prophecies owing to self-labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labeling_theory): a person who is called [stupid, anything] eventually thinks of himself as [stupid, anything] and tends to act as such - ultimately _becoming_ that. You want to address this as well. Assuming you weren't the one who initially called him stupid, it's usually a sign that teachers or his peers are calling him that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not knowing your son I can only speculate, but the whole description sorta hits home with me, so here's my stab into the dark and advice:

He's probably incredibly bored by school. I know second hand that Japanese schools don't have particularly inventive teaching methods, and he's probably bored by sitting and listening all day to a teacher who may not be very interesting talk about topics he doesn't have any particular interest in. It can bore the crap out of anyone, and nobody wants to have anything to do with boring topics when there are alternatives (friends and games).

Fundamentally the things being taught in school *are* fascinating, the problem is that the presentation can often obscure that fact and that often no basis is being taught for *why* the subject is actually quite interesting. Also the fact that all subjects taught in school are fundamentally interconnected is often missed in my experience. So your son may be wondering what he's supposed to do with this useless knowledge he's supposed to retain and/or why it might be interesting to anyone at all.

To help him there, you can try to fill in the gaps between the theoretical world of school, practical daily life and the real world. Should he suddenly develop an interest in astronomy for example, he'll gobble up physics, maths and other related subjects automatically, because he can suddenly see how they help him understand a topic he cares about. Or an interest in war machinery will feed an interest in history. And on and on it goes. Help him find something to connect the dots. A new hobby could be it, but perhaps he also needs more exposure to the real world in the form of travel, a job, practical responsibilities or something of that sort. Whatever is practically available to you and sticks with him.

Comment: Best of luck to you guys, hope it works out!